# How to generate key using KeyGenerator for FingerPrint API in Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, audio-fingerprinting, key-generator

I am trying to implement the FingerPrint API for my application. I am following the Google's [Fingerprint Dialog sample](http://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html) for this purpose.

It works fine if `compileSdkVersion=23` and `minSdkVersion=23` **but my application's `compileSdkVersion` is 21 and `minSdkVersion` is 14. For this purpose, I am using `FingerprintManagerCompat` instead of `FingerprintManager` which works fine but the issue is with the Key generation.**

```
android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException;
android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
```

Keystore package and its classes are not available to generate the key, all the supported algorithms for the key generation available in 18+ API versions, anybody can guide me how to generate the key to support lower versions, please?

Comment: The devices lower than these does not have finger print sensor, so i dnt think so it would be necessary to give backward support.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at FingerprintManagerCompat javadoc:

> A class that coordinates access to the fingerprint hardware.
>
> On platforms before M, this class behaves as there would be no
>   fingerprint hardware available.

Looking at the source code:

```
final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (version >= 23) {
   // a working implementation
   IMPL = new Api23FingerprintManagerCompatImpl();
} else {
   // an empty stub
   IMPL = new LegacyFingerprintManagerCompatImpl();
}
```

If your device is below API VERSION 23, the LegacyFingerprintManagerCompatImpl is used, and this is only a STUB. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean hasEnrolledFingerprints(Context context) {
   return false;
}
@Override
public boolean isHardwareDetected(Context context) {
   return false;
}
```

You cannot use such feature in older device. Those API (some from android.security.keystore) are available only on Android M